# Animated show where Ghost Rider put Penance Stare on Galactus

Tags: marvel, tv, episode-identification, galactus, ghost-rider

I remember watching this animated marvel show episode show but don't know the name:

**Plot:** Galactus attacking search and hell lot of marvel characters comes and fight with Galactus. Fantastic four, Ghost Rider and some Avengers, etc. There were many.

**Climax:** Galactus was kind of half defeated already and then Ghost Rider comes and puts Penance Stare on him.

**Language:** English

**Year:** Saw in 2000-2005ish

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is *[Fantastic Four: When Calls Galactus](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0577666/)*

> Galactus' new slave and herald, double-crossing Terrax, asks Fantastic
> Four for help. However, Johnny's Inhuman girlfriend Frankie supports
> Galactus. Thor arrives to help the Fantastic Four and even mythical
> Ghost Rider intervenes.

Comment: At your next performance appraisal, you need to get “watching cartoons” added to your job description.

Comment: That episode is based on [FF volume 1 #243.](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_243). In the comic, it's Doctor Strange who freaks out Galactus by casting a spell.